# Preload sound with soundmanager v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I need to preload sound to my site with this script:

```
    soundManager.setup({
   url: '/swf/',
   flashVersion:9,
   useFlashBlock:false,
   onready: function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: "son_1",
        url: 'son/son_1.mp3'
     });
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: "son_2",
        url: 'son/son_2.mp3'
     });
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: "son_3",
        url: 'son/son_3.mp3'
     });
   }
});

function sound(id)
{


    snd = soundManager.createSound(
    {
        id : "son_" + id,
        url: 'son/son_' + id + '.mp3',
        autoLoad: true
    });
    snd.play();

}
```

I have test the `<audio>` and `<sound>` balise but not work
Always the sound play 2 seconde after click...

What is the solution plz ?? Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `autoLoad` to true
and `autoPlay` to false

```
soundManager.createSound({id:blah,url:blah.mp3,autoLoad:true,autoPlay:false});
```

replace "blah" with whatever you need.